# Выборка из MySql в диапазоне дат

Tags: mysql, дата

есть таблица в формате

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `statistic` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_org` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_driver` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `coins` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `data` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=20110 ;
```

сейчас делаю простую выборку из таблицы по ИД таким запросом

```
$result =  $connection->query("SELECT * FROM statistic WHERE `id_user`=".$users[$i]['id']);
```

И есть даты в диапазоне которых нужно сделать выборку
к примеру 20-03-2019 29-03-2019

Вопрос: каким образом возможно сформулировать запрос, чтоб в результате получить только нужную выборку данных.

Дата в базе хранится в формате юникс метки.

Comment: Добавить во WHERE ещё одно условие отбора - по датам.

Comment: Не храните дату в БД в виде unix метки, это не удобно. Но раз она у вас хранится так, то `data between метка1 and метка2`. А значения для мепток посчитайте сами перед запросом или в самом запросе с помощью `unix_timestamp()`. P.S. никогда не подставляйте в запрос непосредственно значения переменных, используйте подготавливаемые запросы и привязку значений. https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.bindparam.php

Comment: Как точно соотносится значение в поле date BIGINT и интепретируемая по нему дата. UNIX timestamp? Если да - можно ли гарантировать совпадение временнОй зоны хранимых данных и условия отбора?

Comment: На всякий случай: `SELECT CAST(20190101121530 AS DATETIME);` -> `2019-01-01 12:15:30`...

Answer (score 1):

Хранить дату лучше в формате `datetime`, но т.к. у вас числовой тип, то можно как-то так:

```
$from = strtotime('20-03-2019');
$to = strtotime('29-03-2019' . ' 23:59:59');

$result =  $connection->query("SELECT * FROM statistic WHERE `id_user`=".$users[$i]['id']
                              ." AND `data` >= {$from} AND `data` <= {$to}");

// Вариант 2
$result =  $connection->query("SELECT * FROM statistic WHERE `id_user`=".$users[$i]['id']
                              ." AND `data` BETWEEN {$from} AND {$to}");
```